How to correctly use FSM in aiogram for registering next message handler?
I want to make an analog of register_next_step_handler from telebot for aiogram. As I have already understood, I have to use FSM for this. However, I can't figure out what I should do with this example:
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == " Prohibit publication for a while")
def prohibit_sending_messages_button(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Enter the blocking time in minutes (0 for cancellation; multiply by 60/1440 to indicate hours/days):")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, block_sending_for_minutes)

def block_sending_for_minutes(message):
    global acceptable_time
    # Change acceptable_time value to actual time + chosen time (can be mathematical expression)
    acceptable_time = message.date + eval(message.text) * 60
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"The ban on sending messages will be in effect until {datetime.fromtimestamp(acceptable_time).strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y")}")

I try do this:
@router.message(is_admin & F.text == " Prohibit publication for a while")
async def prohibit_sending_messages_button(message: Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    await state.set_state(Form.blocking_time)
    await message.answer("Enter the blocking time in minutes (0 for cancellation; multiply by 60/1440 to indicate hours/days):")


@router.message(Form.blocking_time)
async def block_sending_for_minutes(message: Message) -> None:
    global acceptable_time
    # Change acceptable_time value to actual time + chosen time (can be mathematical expression)
    acceptable_time = message.date + eval(await message.text) * 60
    await message.answer(f"The ban on sending messages will be in effect until {datetime.fromtimestamp(acceptable_time).strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y")}")

My questions:

Do I need to create a separate class for this, if so, should I put all the FSM classes in a separate file and what is the correct name for the class and the variable itself?
Do I need to use state.clear(), if so, how do I get state, if not, then it turns out that I just don't use this class anymore?

